# Angular2 best way to avoid multiple instances of a single component

Tags: angular, singleton, instance

What's your best practice to avoid a component to trigger multiple times the same function when leaving and coming back to some page ?

I went into this issue when creating a user list that would trigger some `getContent()` each time the user scroll to the bottom of the page. The problem is each time you leave and come back to user list page, it will create a new instance of the service and trigger x times the `getContent()` function.

I'm using `ngOnDestroy()` and reset the `getContent()` method to avoid multiple calls but I'm sure either there's something wrong in my code or there is a best way to do it... Than :

```
ngOnDestroy() {
     this.items.clear();
     this.getContent = ():void => {};
};
```

Thanks a lot for your advices/opinions.

M

PS: plnkr is down, I will post one ASAP

Comment: Even if this is not about http calls, just use a service which are instantiated only once if provided only once and do the call there if it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Günter. I read that post but that only applies to the Observable while I'm trying to avoid multiple calls of a single instruction... It seems like there's something surviving, not about the observable because RxJS automatically unsubscribes after conditions are met but about the function or the component itself (?)...

Comment: A global provided service is provided only once and if you execute code in the constructor then it is only executed once. This doesn't need to use `Observable`.

Comment: That's exactly the behaviour I was expecting but it's not :/ wait until I get plnkr working @GünterZöchbauer